# zeromq php extension/binding on 64bit windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: php, zend-framework, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, zeromq

As the question heading speaks for its self. Any one having luck running zeromq as a php extension on Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit. Regardless on Apache or IIS.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: yes On 32 bit it works fine, Problem is with 64 bit.